# Using multiple firewalls and multiple guards

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, symfony-security

I've got a Symfony 5.1 (fullstack) application and I'm using Api Platform. Now I want to use API tokens to access the API (using [Custom Authentication System with Guard](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html)), but already logged in users should be able to access the API without a token.

I've used the example from the Symfony documentation about [Multiple Guard Authenticators](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/multiple_guard_authenticators.html) and added a second authenticator:

```
$container->loadFromExtension('security', [
    // ...
    'firewalls' => [
        'api' => [
            'context' => 'my_context',
            'pattern' => '^/api',
            'guard' => [
                'entry_point' => LoginFormAuthenticator::class,
                'authenticators' => [
                    LoginFormAuthenticator::class,
                    ApiTokenAuthenticator::class,
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'default' => [
            'context' => 'my_context',
            'anonymous' => true,
            'lazy' => true,
            'guard' => [
                'authenticators' => [
                    LoginFormAuthenticator::class,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
);
```

When I use `TokenAuthenticator` as the `entry_point`, requests to `^/api/` are not accessible by logged in users. They'll get a `401 Unauthorized` ("A Token was not found in the TokenStorage.").

When I use `ApiTokenAuthenticator` as the `entry_point`, (XMLHttp-)requests to `^/api/` are redirected to `/login` instead of a `401 Unauthorized`.

How can I have API endpoints that are accessible by both authenticators?

Edit: Thanks to Cerad, I've added `context` to both firewalls, as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#reference-security-firewall-context). Didn't make any difference.

Comment: I don't think the link in your question is really applicable.  This [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#frequently-asked-questions) might be better.  I think you need to mess with the firewall context but these sorts of things are always tricky and I'm not really up to speed with the api platform.

Comment: And a bit off-topic perhaps but since you are using 5.1 you might want to experiment with the new [enable_authenticator_manager](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-updated-security-system) parameter as well.

Comment: I think I need multiple firewalls, because I don't want to have other pages than /api/ be available with an api token. I'll look into `context`! (and you don't have to understand api platform, it's unrelated to the question but added for context)

Comment: Firewall context didn't help, but I'll dive into the new Security system.